# When concatenating strings in foreach loop the result is wrong

Tags: xml, string, list, concatenation

So the think is that I have a List of strings that contains filenames i.e. "c001z020102". I'm trying to loop through this list to download xml data from the specific web page.

```
 foreach (string el in fileNames)
            {
                 a = client.DownloadString("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/" + el + ".xml");
                 a = a.Replace("\"ISO-8859-2\"", "\"UTF-8\"");
                 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(a);
                 //rest of the code to process the data
            }
```

But the result of this url to download from looks like this: "*.xml://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/" + el*"
So as you can see it adds the extension at the beginning. I've tried to do it with stringbuilder etc. and still doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: It rather seems the `el` contains a MSWin line end.

Comment: Off-topic, but it is usually dangerous to overwrite the encoding in any text document. Do you have a good reason for doing this?

Comment: @kimbert Yeah I know but otherwise I couldn't process this document because exception is thrown about wrong encoding that c# doesn't support. I just need to extract a couple of data from this file so there is nothing wrong with replacing it.

Comment: @choroba You are right, I used Trim() on all file names and it worked. Thank you!